# Is it a bad idea to create a model that deals with realm db and a model for use

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, realm

I just started using realm in my ios swift project, and noticed several issues related to accessing realm objects from different threads.

So I decided to have, for each model, an associate realm model.

For example, for my `User` model, I will have `UserRealm` model which has the same attributes. However, I use `UserRealm` to read/write the db, and `User` to use through out the App.

Is this a bad idea? Does it affect the efficiency of realm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, copying the objects back and forth will obviously cost performance. If your model is relational with links between the objects, you are also likely to lose those as you copy out individual objects.

What kinds of threading issues do you see? As long as you handover the objects between the threads you should be safe. Check out https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#passing-instances-across-threads for examples.

Comment: My application does not do a lot of db writes. Most of the work is done when loading the data on starting the application. Then dealing with the objects in memory. However, realm requires fetching an object every time  you use it (because different threads could use it)

Comment: Re-fetching the object on another thread should be very cheap if it was already loaded on startup (in that case it will likely still be cached in memory).